# Dataset for predicting gender

Tags: python, facebook, machine-learning, neural-network, supervised-learning

Can anyone guide me towards any dataset which consists of questions/survey based on psychology which when answered in full extent can tell you the gender if the person taking the test?

I need it to create a tool through which we can detect the patterns of fake profiles on the social platforms.

I know a few groups which are gender-specific (e.g. for mothers, for women private talk) but the opposite gender tries to trash it getting into the group pretending to be female.

I know it sounds silly for now, but anyone who wants to join these group can go through the questionnaire and the AI can detect it's gender.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Off-topic for SO, but see [opendata.se]

Comment: Your plan relies on the people who want to trash the group to answer the questions truthfully, which I think is quite optimistic.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dataset that I came across on [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/crowdflower/twitter-user-gender-classification). It does not have question-answer pairs from surveys, but the project was mainly about attempting to predict gender based on users' tweets. Not sure if you need your dataset in questionnaire format, but if not then you can check this out: 
[Twitter User Gender Classification](https://www.kaggle.com/crowdflower/twitter-user-gender-classification)